# How can I store Coding Projects Locally but sync related documents to iCloud Drive?

Tags: macos, cloud

I recently converted into the Apple ecosystem with a MacBook (MacOS Ventura) and iPhone 11 after using Windows and Android for almost a decade. I have many Git repositories I will need to keep on the computer, which after some research, I decided would stay only locally on the MacBook and not on iCloud Drive.

The problem, then is that I want to sync documents related to these projects - including slideshows, text files, documents, spreadsheets, and images - that are not part of the Git repository but part of the projects - on iCloud Drive. My first thought is to use the .nosync for each of these, but the other problem is that iCloud is notoriously hard to navigate to, so ideally, my entire "Computing" folder is located at "~/Computing".

My second thought is to store what I want synced on iCloud, then alias it to the ~/Computing folder, and this is what I am doing for now. But I would love a solution that I can set up once and never have to "maintain."

How do I prevent the Git repositories from getting synced while syncing the others to iCloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pondering the issue further, I realized I can write a shell script that automates symlinks for all of the lowest-level directories so that I can keep the same structure, cd around within the local directory, but still add git repositories.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

icloud_dev_dir="$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/dev"
personal_dev_dir="$HOME/Computing"

# Function to create aliases for files within a directory
create_aliases_for_files() {
    local source_dir=$1
    local target_dir=$2

    find "$source_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        local file_name=$(basename "$file")
        ln -s "$file" "$target_dir/$file_name"
        sleep 1
        echo "Created alias: $file -> $target_dir/$file_name"
    done
}

# Function to create aliases for lowest-level directories
create_aliases_for_directories() {
    local path=$1
    local base_dir=$2

    local relative_path=${path#"$icloud_dev_dir"}
    local target_dir="$base_dir$relative_path"

    if [[ "$path" != "$icloud_dev_dir" ]]; then
        if [[ "$path" -ef "$target_dir" ]]; then
            echo "Skipping self-referential symlink: $path"
        elif [[ -z "$(find "$path" -mindepth 1 -type d)" ]]; then
            ln -s "$path" "$target_dir"
            sleep 1
            echo "Created alias: $path -> $target_dir"
        else
            mkdir -p "$target_dir"
            create_aliases_for_files "$path" "$target_dir"
            sleep 1
            echo "Created directory: $target_dir"
        fi
    fi
}

# Create aliases for lowest-level directories
find "$icloud_dev_dir" -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' directory; do
    create_aliases_for_directories "$directory" "$personal_dev_dir"
done
```

Now, I just need to make sure I am adding files and folders to iCloud Drive, and then I run the script again *only when I need to use it with the git repo*.